# Cannot write data to Serial Port

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, bluetooth

I am trying to write data to Serial Port. I use this way:

```
 QBluetoothSocket *socket;
 socket = new QBluetoothSocket(QBluetoothServiceInfo::RfcommProtocol);
    socket->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        QByteArray  byteArr;
            QDataStream out(&byteArr, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
            out << 1 << '\n';        //if plusbutton is pushedm then send zero
            socket.write(byteArr);
            qDebug()<<socket.write(byteArr)<<endl;
```

But I get in return:

W/libA_for_w8.so( 6443): (null):0 ((null)): qt.bluetooth.android:
Socket::writeData:  QBluetoothSocket::ConnectingState false

W/libA_for_w8.so( 6443): (null):0 ((null)): qt.bluetooth.android:
 Socket::writeData:  QBluetoothSocket::ConnectingState false

D/libA_for_w8.so( 6443): ..\A_for_w8\widget.cpp:68 (void Widget::on_plus_clicked()): -1

D/libA_for_w8.so( 6443):

So, nothing is written to there. 
It seems, that the code is ok, but it doesn't work.
Can you tell me what's wrong? 
Thank you.

P.S.

I checked socket is open .
socket->isOpen return true and I get: 
W/libA_for_w8.so( 9638): (null):0 ((null)): qt.bluetooth.android: Socket::writeData:  QBluetoothSocket::UnconnectedState false

D/libA_for_w8.so( 9638): ..\A_for_w8\widget.cpp:70 (void Widget::on_plus_clicked()): -1

Comment: _"It seems, that the code is ok, but it doesn't work."_ Huh??

Comment: You have no single line of code to check for possibe runtime errors or such.

Comment: Well, I did not say, the code is 100% correct, but I personally do not see errors here, let's put it this way.
"You have no single line of code to check for possibe runtime errors or such" - how to do that?

Comment: Check if `open()` failed in 1st place. Also no one can check what's going wrong, unless you provide a [MCVE] here.

Comment: Done, socket is open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to connect the socket to an endpoint before you can successfully write anything. There must be a running Bluetooth service somewhere, to which you connect using `connectToService()`. After the `connected()` signal has been emitted, you can write data.

It doesn't appear that `QBluetoothSocket` has a `waitForConnected()` function, as `QAbstractSocket` and its subclasses do. This means you can use something like `QSignalSpy` to wait for the `connected()` signal, or, if you don't care so much about efficiency, just a busy-wait loop would do.

EDIT:

As pointed out in the comment, waiting for events to happen is the whole point of Qt's main event loop. Using the `waitFor*` methods or another event loop is pretty inefficient, and definitely goes against the spirit of Qt. So the *best* solution to writing data only after the socket is connected is to connect a `writeData()` slot to the `connected()` signal of `QBluetoothSocket`.

Comment: This is correct, except that the suggestion to use `QSignalSpy` in non-test code is horrendous. The `waitFor` methods are absent because they are horrible performance-wise and lead people to write spaghetti code. **You react to signals by connecting your code (slots/functors) to them, not waiting for them explicitly! The event loop does the waiting: it's its sole job.** You don't wait for things to happen, you let your code run when they happen. Much cleaner, and much better performing.

Comment: Good point @KubaOber, I updated my answer. I suggested busy-waiting mostly because the OP had other posts with `waitFor*` speckled throughout, so I thought it would be easily digestible.